# Nullary Arithmetic Product (at Wiki)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In [Nullary Arithmetic Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#Nullary_arithmetic_product) at Wiki, we are given a sequence of numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3\ldots$

The product of the first $m$ elements of this sequence is given there by

$P_m=a_m \cdot P_{m-1}$ where $P_1= a_1$ and $P_0 = 1$

Quite a peculiar form, it seems to me. Wouldn't a more standard form of the definition be:

$$P_m=\begin{cases}
a_1,&\text{if }m=1\\
a_m\cdot P_{m-1},&\text{if }m>1
\end{cases}$$

EDIT:

Or alternatively...

$$P_m=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }m=0\\
a_m\cdot P_{m-1},&\text{if }m>0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The two forms agree, except for $P_0$.  It is standard that this is $1$, but your version leaves this undefined.

Comment: (Right-click on the displayed expression to see how I produced it.) It’s a very natural form, analogous to defining the sum by $S_0=0$ and $S_m=S_{m-1}+a_m$ for $m>0$. It’s standard that an empty sum is $0$ and an empty product, $1$.

Comment: "Allowing a "product" with only one or zero factors reduces the number of cases to be considered in many mathematical formulas. Such "products" are natural starting points in induction proofs, as well as in algorithms. For these reasons, the "empty product is one convention" is common practice in mathematics and computer programming." Your answer is there in your link itself

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the editing. To use a programming analogy to my 2nd alternative (see edit), if you want to calculate the product of the numerical contents of a variable length array, you might initialize an accumulator variable Prod=1. Then loop through the array multiplying Prod by each element of the array in turn. If the final result was 1, either the array was empty (and no multiplication actually occurred) or every element was equal to 1. What has this got to do with $0^0$?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, just as one initializes an additive accumulator to $0$. One can think of $x^0$ as the product of $0$ factors no matter what $x$, is, and if you do, then in particular $0^0$ should be $1$. This also turns out to be the value that generally leads to simpler expressions in combinatorial applications.

Answer (score 2):

Why so? Because you abhorr products with zero factors? But then - does a product with one factor make sense? Wouldn't then
$$ P_m=\begin{cases}a_1\cdot a_2,&\text{if $m=2$}\\a_m\cdot P_{m-1},&\text{if $m>2$}\end{cases}$$
be even better? Just as this variant would leave the case $m=1$ undefined, your variant leaves the case $m=0$ undefined. Since the definition is otherwise consistent (i.e., we always have $P_m=a_mP_{m-1}$ if $P_m,a_m,P_{m-1}$ are defined) the definition that includes $P_0=1$ is preferable. (And after all, the Wikipedia is specifically about the empty product, so it certainly should consider the case $m=0$).

Comment: Just looking at the definition itself. The $P_0$ seems like an unnecessary contrivance if you are simply defining products of finite sequences of numbers. But I guess there is more to it than simply defining such products. I see from the article that somehow this $P_0$ is equated to $x^0$ for all $x\in N$.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: The rhetorical gripe over a product with one factor reminds me of the Ancient Greeks' belief that two, not one, was the first number—one is not numerous!

Comment: Depending on your application, you may legitimately want at least two elements in your input list to be multiplied together as you suggest. Or you may want at least one element and return that single value if there is only one element in the list. Or you may return some numerical value (maybe 0 or 1) if the list was empty. Of course, in this case, you could also get a 0 or 1 by multiplying 2 or more elements. It all seems really quite arbitrary -- hardly some universal mathematical truth as seems to be suggested here.